# How to set double press the `esc` key shortcut?

Tags: qt

I am using qt, I am wondering is it possible set double press <kbd>Esc</kbd> shortcut? I want to have an effect, when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> twice, a function is called.

Thanks

Comment: "double click of Esc shortcut"? What's that supposed to be? Please describe in more detail, what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on each pressing ESC   make

```
PRESSED+=1;
```

and if on any next press

```
     if (PRESSED >=2) {
        //fire event here
        ...
        // Dont forget to reset PRESSED for next usage
       PRESSED=0;
      }
```

in case `PRESSED` yet not equals `"2"` (if user pressed it once) after 1-3 seconds reset it to `0;` and fire event for single press.

for the situation when u dont want fire SinglePressEvent in case doublepress just delay singlepress event for 1-2 seconds to wait for second press.. if second press does not appear fire singlepressevent.